# gridstack how to block resize without blocking dragging?

Tags: gridstack

I see the option to make it 'static'(not draggable, not resizable) but how to just block the resize option ?

https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute `data-gs-no-resize`. Please check out official [demo site](http://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/) there is a block with image inside and it has fixed size.

You can also set this property in runtime using `resizable(el, false)`. See https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js#resizableel-val

Answer (score 1):

Disable all items If you need lock when initialize.

```
// for multipple gridStack
let grids = GridStack.initAll({
    disableResize: true 
})

// for single gridStack
let grid = GridStack.init({
    disableResize: true 
})
```